# RecyclerView Decoration doesn't scroll correctly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which uses a simple line separator Decoration.

The decoration is fine except when a NEW item is added to the bottom of the recycler and scrolled into view, the decoration is initially drawn in it's final location and then the view underneath scrolls into place, but the decoration doesn't scroll.

The desired behavior would be for the decoration to be drawn in it's starting location and then scroll into position along with the new item.

Here's the relevant portions of the Decoration:

```
class NormalDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int spacing;
    private Drawable drawable;

    NormalDecoration(Context context) {
        spacing = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.chat_separator_height);
        drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.chat_divider);
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);

        if (applySpacing(view, parent)) {
            outRect.top += spacing;
        }
    }

    boolean applySpacing(View view, RecyclerView parent) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

        return position != -1 && position < mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int dividerLeft = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int dividerRight = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        for(int index = parent.getChildCount() - 1 ; index >= 0 ; --index) {
            View view = parent.getChildAt(index);

            if(applySpacing(view, parent)) {
                RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

                int dividerTop = view.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
                int dividerBottom = dividerTop + spacing;

                drawable.setBounds(dividerLeft, dividerTop, dividerRight, dividerBottom);
                drawable.draw(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Adapter contains the following helper:

```
class Adapter {
    public void add(final int index, final IChatMessageItem item) {
        mItems.add(index, item);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }
}
```

And here's how I add the item to the recycler that results in unacceptable scrolling behavior:

```
...
adapter.add(index, item);
layout.scrollToPosition(index);
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `view.getTranslationX()`, `getTranslationY()`, and `getAlpha()` respectively to animate the decoration along with the view moving.

If you just draw a divider, you might want to use the official [support decoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html) which also does the above mentioned.

I also wrote an article about this in detail [here](http://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2015/11/18/decorations-animations.html).

Comment: I use one of several decorations, this was just the simplest.  But they all exhibit the same behavior.  I'll take a look at the article.

Comment: @DavidBerry Also here are some sample decorations: https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations

Comment: Thanks!  The trick seems to actually be the alpha, and not the translation, but what's important is it works.